# Smarty - How can i set a max ( 5 ) pages to show on pagination from a calling query

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, sql

Wondering how to set a max number of results from a query, for example if there is more than 10 result pages display 1,2,3,4,5...and last (10) and so on.. I am using smarty and could not figure how to make work.

```
                <!-- .pagination starts -->
                <div class="pagination-wrapper1">
                        <ul class="pagination">

                            {if $active_page eq $smarty.section.page_num.index+1}
                                <li class="previous-off"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Previous</li>
                            {else}
                                <li class="previous-on"><a href="#" onclick="ajax_reload_ct_function({$active_page-1})"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Previous</a></li>
                            {/if}


                            {section name="page_num" loop=$pages}
                                {if $active_page eq $smarty.section.page_num.index+1}
                                    <li class="active">{$smarty.section.page_num.index+1}</li>
                            {else}
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="ajax_reload_ct_function({$smarty.section.page_num.index+1})">{$smarty.section.page_num.index+1}</a></li>
                            {/if}
                            {/section}


                            {if $active_page eq $smarty.section.page_num.index}
                                <li class="next-off">Next <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></li>
                            {else}
                                <li class="next"><a href="#" onclick="ajax_reload_ct_function({$active_page+1})">Next <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a></li>
                            {/if}


                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.pagination ends -->
```

This is how my pagination works currently:

[image: current pagination with provided code]

And this is an example of how should be...hope someone can help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about smarty. I think its some sort of template engine.

But i can give you the idea how to do it with php.

so in the pagination you will always know which page you are currently in. So in this case you are in page 39.

what you can do is  run two loops, one decrementing the value of current page 5 times like

38 37 36 35 34 in the page

the other one will increment current page by 5

40 41 42 43 44 in the same page

so your page will echo these in the same div so you will end up with the pagination showing aboe.

ofcourse you need to do checks to make sure while decrementing the value doesnt go below 1

and while incrementing the value doent go above maximum page.

Hope this helps you.

OR

You can run a single loop starting at current_page -5  and going all the way to current_page+5

I am sure you can adjust the logic to show 5 pages instead of 10